# Weird eigen matrix multiplication behavior when using row-major matrices

Tags: c++, eigen, matrix-multiplication, row-major-order

The following is working just fine for me:

```
using Mat4 = Eigen::Matrix4f;
using Vec3 = Eigen::Vector3f;

class Camera {
public:
  Vec3 pos = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
  Vec3 forward = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
  Vec3 up = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };
  float vfov = degrees(45.0f);
  float near_plane = 0.1f;
  float far_plane = 100.0f;

  Mat4 cameraToScreen(float aspect_ratio) const {
    Mat4 result;

    float tanHalfFovy = tan(vfov *0.5f);
    float x_scale = 1.0f / (aspect_ratio * tanHalfFovy);
    float y_scale = 1.0f / (tanHalfFovy);

    result << 
      x_scale, 0, 0, 0,
      0, y_scale, 0, 0,
      0, 0, -(far_plane + near_plane) / (far_plane - near_plane), -1.0f,
      0, 0, -2.0f * near_plane * far_plane / (far_plane - near_plane), 0;
    return result;
  }

  Mat4 worldToCamera() const {
    Mat4 result;

    Vec3 p = pos;
    Vec3 f = forward.normalized();
    Vec3 r = f.cross(up).normalized();
    Vec3 u = r.cross(f).normalized();

    result << 
      r.x(), u.x(), -f.x(), 0.0f,
      r.y(), u.y(), -f.y(), 0.0f,
      r.z(), u.z(), -f.z(), 0.0f,
      -r.dot(p), -u.dot(p), f.dot(p), 1.0f;

    return result;
  }

  Mat4 worldToScreen(float aspect_ratio) const {
    return cameraToScreen(aspect_ratio) * worldToCamera();
  }
};
```

However, since this is going to OpenGL, and I don't like dealing with transpositions, I though I could simply switch to row-major matrices:

```
using Mat4 = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4, Eigen::RowMajor>;
```

Unfortunately, everything broke. Interestingly enough, inverting the final matrix multiplication (which is wrong) fixes the issue:

```
Mat4 worldToScreen(float aspect_ratio) const {
  return worldToCamera() * cameraToScreen(aspect_ratio);
}
```

It's almost as if eigen performed the matrix multiplication with the assumption that the storage was column-major, regardless of my template tag, but that can't be right.

I tested both matrices individually, and they are performing as I want in row-major mode when used in isolation, it's only the product of both matrices that's wrong.

What am I not understanding with the way Eigen handles row-major matrices?

**Edit**:

Here's effectively how I send the data to OpenGL. My code has a lot of additional boilerplate, but it boils down to this:

```
struct CameraData {
  Mat4 world_to_screen ;
};

void draw(Camera const& cam) {
  CameraData cam_data;

  // I remove the transposed() call when using Eigen::RowMajor
  cam_data.world_to_screen = cam.worldToScreen(16.0f/9.0f).transposed();

  // Camera data has a permanent ubo binding point shared by all programs.
  glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, cam_data_ubo);
  glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(cam_data), &cam_data);

  //.. perform drawing
}
```

and the glsl:

```
#version 420

in vec3 vertex;

layout (std140) uniform CameraData {
  mat4 world_to_screen;
};

void main() {
  gl_Position = world_to_screen * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: You are right in principle. Can you show what you do with the matrix afterwards (i.e. what exactly breaks; how do you upload it to the GPU and what operations do you do in GLSL?). Obviously, some of these things must be adapted when you switch from col major to row major. If you didn't, it is natural that some things break. I can't really explain why it works when you invert the multiplication order, though. I could explain it for special cases where `transpose(worldToCamera) = worldToCamera` and `transpose(cameraToScreen) = cameraToScreen`, but not for the general case.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Done. AFAIK, the only that should change is the call to `transposed()` before sending the data to the shader.

Comment: That looks quite right. Can you debug it by printing the matrices with the `<<` operator? These outputs should be equal, no matter if you use row major or col major layout. At what point do the results start to differ? Btw, is there a reason why you don't want the transpose? Other than a slightly more coherent data access at this one time, I can't see an advantage.

Comment: The way you initialize your `worldToCamera()` matrix looks wrong. Note that the `<< ,`-initialization in Eigen is always row-major.

Comment: @chtz But I would still expect the error to be consistent when switching between row-major and column-major if that was the case.